# Python graph with three entities and legends

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have three lists in python. the lists are given below

```
Server_name=['server_1','server_1','server_1', 'server_1','server_2', 'server_2','server_2','server_2']
Month_name=['may','may','june','aug','may','june','july','sept']
Error_count=[10,20,10,30,40,10,20,50]
```

I want to plot a graph something like below

[image]

The above diagram shows that the for all the servers and corresponding month the total count of errors are taken and the graph is plot.

I have tried different scenarios but was unable to get the perfect graph with legends and total count for all three entities.

How should I built my code so I can get the above graph, please suggest

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using vincent module. It is used to produce these type of graphs

https://github.com/wrobstory/vincent